# Make my own video conversion program? Viable?

Tags: video

How are video conversion programs made? Do they seriously understand every single file format of every single type they implement or is it using direct show filters or something? Basically i am interested in making my own but if i actually have to research every single file format to convert then i think ill pass O_O

So whats the go, direct show filters? libraries? are the free?
Like say i want to convert mp4 to avi or mkv and what not; where should i start my learnings >:D

Answer (score 2):

Start [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/), ffmpeg is open source and the defacto standard as a free codec library.

Comment: i'm having problems trying to compile it with MinGW, any idea what's wrong with this? Sorry idk how to do code blocks

<code>
#! /bin/bash
./configure –-extra-cflags="-mno-cygwin -mms-bitfields" –-extra-ldflags=”-Wl -add-stdcall-alias” –-enable-memalign-hack –-target-os=mingw32 –-enable-shared –-disable-static
</code>

I get the following errors
<code>
$ ./mingMake
Unknown option "--extra-cflags=-mno-cygwin".
See ./configure --help for available options.
</code>
but i did ./configure --help and indeed --extra-cflags is an options, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: ugh dammit, i don't know how to do code blocks sorry! trying to google how to know but i keep getting code::blocks results lmao

Comment: try to look for a precompiled version for windows -- perhaps ask on the "VLC" forums.